# Rails request spec is not making put request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I decided to write some request specs, in addition to my cucumber scenarios. But failed on my first example:

So there is this put method in my goalsController:

```
   def achieve
        @goal.update_attribute(:achieved, true)
        redirect_to :back
   end
```

And this is example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Achievements" do
  before(:all) do
    @bob = Factory(:user, :email => "bob@mail.com", :password => "qweqwe", :password_confirmation => "qweqwe", :money => 500)
    @achieve = Factory(:goal, :user => @bob, :title => "Notebook", :price => 100, :achieved => false)
    login_user('bob@mail.com', 'qweqwe')
  end
    it 'can not be achieved twice' do
      visit dashboard_path
      put achieve_user_goal_path(@bob, @achieve) #Passes it well
      @achieve.reload #same with or without this line
      @achieve.achieved.should equal true #Fails
    end
end
```

So after put request 'achieved' field becomes true. It works perfectly in my app, and in cucumber step, but not in this rspec example. It's like rspec just ignores line with 'put'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how this works correctly, RSpec uses the Test::Unit helpers from Rails.  If reads the controller name from what you are describing, so you would need to `describe AchievementsController`, and not just some string.  You don't visit a page then send `put`, you just describe the controller and send `put`.

That said, when you are using the capybara integration testing helpers, the unit test helpers like `put` and `get` probably don't do what you want, as they will be executed outside of the context of the browser driver.  You should instruct Capybara to click the required link or button (or perform whatever action the user performs).

Comment: I want to test that everything works correctly if user tries to request this put again. For example, if he opened two same pages and tries to click "Achieve" on both of them.

Comment: I didn't get that from your question; testing race conditions is not very easy to do, as far as I know, but if you don't need the requests to execute simultaneously, just vist the path and click the button twice.

Comment: On next visit of this path there will not be this button, because goal is achieved. But if earlier user opened another page, then it will have this button and user will be able to click it there again. My code already safe for this behavior (i inserted not all code from #achieve action), and I just want to test it with request spec :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe it's possible, since the tests execute synchronously.  You *may* be able to use threads to set something up, but it's not something I have experience with.  You need to update your question, as this is not what you asked.

Comment: If fact, I can do the same if I will fire put request for same user and already achieved goal, can't I? =) So my question is correct, because problem is that put request is not working as it should.